# Depends in UI Grid and Edit form

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, ui-form

How can i use depends like in `system.xml` in my ui grid or edit form

lines from `system.xml`

```
<depends>
    <field id="section_id/group_id/field_id">1</field>
</depends>
```